# Not able to hide toolbar on scrolling Fragment layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have my MainActivity layout with AppBarLayout with TabLayout and a ViewPager. I am not able to hide toolbar on scrolling Fragment layout added to my View Pager. But i am able to hide the toolbar which i scroll over the AppBarLayout.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:windowBackground">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:background="?android:windowBackground"
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:background="?android:windowBackground"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="?colorAccent"
            app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabBackground="?android:windowBackground"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="?colorAccent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance.Timber" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this line to `AppBarLayout`: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"`

and remove `app:layout_scrollFlags` from `Toolbar` layout

Comment: That didn't work. Now the toolbar does not hide at all. Toolbar hides only when i add app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" to toolbar layout. And it will hide only when we scroll the AppBar area.

Comment: This is my toolbar:

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

Comment: My viewPager has : app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: It should work. If not try to wrap tab layout and toolbar layout in to single parent layout like FrameLayout and add scroll flags inly in parent layout, nowhere else. And keep `app:layout_behavior` on view pager, also make sure that pager fragments scrolling views do not hava `app:layout_behavior` declared, it is enough to put it on `ViewPager`

Comment: it still doesnt work. My MainActivity layout's parent is a CoordinatorLayout. It only works when i move my ViewPager inside AppBarLayout below tool bar and tablayout which is not an ideal way to fix it i guess.